# Java Grade class, letter grade to number

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that takes a letter grade.  You'd get 4.0 for A, 3.0 for B, and so forth.    If you enter B+ or B-, it will take subtract .3 or add .3 respectively (so B+ would be 3.3).

In my code, when I test a letter like B+ it gives me .3 instead of actually returning the subtracted value of the actual grade. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Grade {
    private String grade;
    private double gradeNum;

    // Constructor
    public Grade(String showGrade) {
        grade = showGrade;
        gradeNum = 0;
    }

    // getNumericGrade method to return grade number
    public double getNumericGrade() {
        String suffix;
        suffix = grade.substring(1);

        if(suffix.equals("+")) {
            gradeNum = gradeNum + .3;
        } else if(suffix.equals("-")) {
            gradeNum = gradeNum - .3;
        }

        String letterGrade = grade.substring(0);

        if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            gradeNum = 4.0;
        } else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            gradeNum = 3.0;
        } else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            gradeNum = 2.0;
        } else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
            gradeNum = 1.0;
        } else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            gradeNum = 0.0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid letter grade");
        }

        return gradeNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reversed. You need to calculate the grade avg and then subtract the value of the - or add the value of the +

Comment: Readability tip:  Instead of a long if-else if-else block, in Java 7, you can do a switch on a String directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first process your letter grades so that it initializes `gradeNum` correctly. Also note that `substring(int index)` returns a subsequence that starts at the index passed till the end of the string. Hence, none of your `letterGrade` if blocks ever matched for inputs like A+, B- etc.

```
if (grade == null || !grade.matches("[A-F][+-]?")) // if grade wasn't specified, or
{// if grade is not between A to F *optionally* followed by a + or - sign
    System.out.println("Invalid letter grade");
    return gradeNum;
}

String letterGrade = grade.substring(0, 1); // pass 1 to exclude + or -

if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
{
    gradeNum = 4.0;
}
else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
{
    gradeNum = 3.0;
}
else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
{
  gradeNum = 2.0;
}
else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
{
    gradeNum = 1.0;
}
else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
{
    gradeNum = 0.0; // return from here if you want F = F- = F+
    return gradeNum; // if you want to invalidate F- and F+ look below
}
/* else // not required; already validated by using regex above
{
    System.out.println("Invalid letter grade");
    return gradeNum; // don't forget to RETURN from here
}*/
```

Then do your suffix processing which adds or subtracts from `gradeNum` which has been initialized properly now.

```
String suffix;
suffix = grade.substring(1);
if (suffix.isEmpty()) { // return early if there's no suffix
    return gradeNum;
} else if (gradeNum == 0.0) { // to invalidate F- and F+
    System.out.println("Invalid letter grade");
    return gradeNum;
}
if(suffix.equals("+") && gradeNum != 4.0) // don't increment if grade is A+ (= A = 4.0)
{
    gradeNum = gradeNum + .3;
}
else if (suffix.equals("-"))
{
    gradeNum = gradeNum - .3;
}
return gradeNum;
```

Comment: This will work, but I do think that an enum is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly I guess my code was out of order which totally makes sense now. Only thing is with the else statement I'm suppose to use that for prompting errors back to the user if he/she enters a invalid letter grade like G or J etc.. why put a return gradeNum in the else?

Comment: @sage88 Yes, `Enum` would make the best fit here but I was just focussed on the flaw in logic here.

Comment: @Shire The return comes after you've printed the error so the user does get to see that s/he passed an invalid grade letter. Secondly, if we don't put the return there the program would continue to process the suffix and could return a gradeNum of 0.3 or -0.3 for invalid grade letters like X+.

Comment: Oh I see, very cool. One last thing is there a way to make A and A+ both be 4.0 since I'm subtracting a .3 from A+ it seems kinda nontrivial to get this to come out correctly without changing the suffix if statement.

Comment: @Shire `if(suffix.equals("+") && gradeNum != 4.0)`

Comment: Hmm this code works been trying to figure how to make so that if you put in anything else besides what is reuired it returns an error for example if you put in an empty "" string for a grade it gives you an error and same for like "ASDHK" garbage stuff.

Comment: @Shire Grade validation added.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this design at all.

Why pay the penalty of recalculating the numerical value again and again?  That makes no sense.

Make Grade immutable and calculate the numeric value in the constructor when you get the letter value.

I'd also have another constructor that would take a float/double and set the letter grade.

You might also think about making Grade an enum, like this:

```
/**
 * Grade encapsulates symbols with values
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744116/java-grade-class-letter-grade-to-number/16744210#16744210
 * @since 5/24/13 6:01 PM
 */
public enum Grade {
    APLUS("A+", 4.3),
    A("A", 4.0),
    AMINUS("A-", 3.7),
    BPLUS("B+", 3.3),
    B("B", 3.0),
    BMINUS("B-", 2.7),
    CPLUS("C+", 2.3),
    C("C", 2.0),
    CMINUS("C-", 1.7),
    DPLUS("D+", 1.3),
    D("D", 1.0),
    DMINUS("D-", 0.7),
    F("F", 0.0);

    private final String symbol;
    private final double value;

    Grade(String symbol, double value) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there are better ways to do this but my teacher insists that we do it this way for computer science 141 class intro to Java.. We can't use enums because they haven't went over that stuff yet. We are ordered to write this program using if statements only.

Comment: My comments about making Grade immutable and doing it in the ctor still stand.

Answer (score 1):

When you get your letter, you use

```
String letterGrade = grade.substring(0);
```

but you never specify an end position.  you can do the following

```
String letterGrade = grade.substring(0,1);  // the end position is exclusive
```

[here's some substring documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)

---

and yes, you should add/subtract your `+` and `-` modification AFTER you set your letter value

Comment: if I'm only looking for the first element is it necessary to do (0,1) when I can just do (0) first element?

Comment: @Shire the first index in (0,1) tells from where to start (inclusive) and the second where to end (exclusive). If you don't pass 1 it will assume till the end of the string and hence return + or - as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-order the code:

```
private String grade;
private double gradeNum;

// Constructor
public Grade(String showGrade)
{
  grade = showGrade;
  gradeNum = 0;
}


// getNumericGrade method to return grade number
public double getNumericGrade()
{
    String letterGrade = grade.substring(0);

    if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
    {
        gradeNum = 4.0;
    }

    else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
    {
        gradeNum = 3.0;

    }

    else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
    {
      gradeNum = 2.0;
    }

    else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
    {
        gradeNum = 1.0;
    }

    else if(letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
    {
        gradeNum = 0.0;
    }


    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid letter grade");
        return -1.0;
    }



    String suffix;
    suffix = grade.substring(1);

    if(suffix.equals("+"))
    {
        gradeNum = gradeNum + .3;

    }

    else if (suffix.equals("-"))
    {
        gradeNum = gradeNum - .3;
    }







    return gradeNum;

}
```

Comment: You should also return after the grade has been found to be invalid.

Comment: None of your letterGrade ifs would match for A+, B- etc.

Answer (score -1):

write a java program that asks the users to enter the letter grade number the program will display the equivalent letter grade and point for the input letter number according to the table below

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're here to help, but you need to meet us halfway. Show what you have tried and how it has failed.